# MAkefiles and linking : libraries order?

Tags: c++, linux, makefile

I've a created a make file to buid a project with multiple folders, multiple libraries. When I perform a full rebuid (i.e. deleting any previous objects and outputs) everything goes well. But if I modify one of the dependencies... it gets compiled (so far so good), the librari is moved to the rightplace, but then thelinker says `"undefined reference to..."` many symbols of this modified lib. I have checked also that the order I put the libraries in the listing of libraries actually matters and I get more or less errors like the one mentioned. What I'm doing wrong? Thank you!!! I'm omitting here the building of the dependencies for simplicity.

```
#===== aliases =====
#--- compiler
CC:=g++
CFLAGS:=-g -Wall -ansi
KDEBUG:=0
APNAME:=MyApp
OBJS:=$(wildcard *.o)

#--- folders
MAINPATH:=/home/entity-k/KLABS/AppFolder
#MAINPATH:=.
SRCDIR:=$(MAINPATH)/src
EXEDIR:=$(MAINPATH)/bin
OBJDIR:=$(MAINPATH)/obj
LIBDIR:=$(MAINPATH)/lib

#--- output file
OUTPUT:=$(EXEDIR)/$(APNAME)

#--- include folders
INCLUDES = -I $(SRCDIR)/include
INCLUDES += -I $(SRCDIR)/kMath
INCLUDES += -I $(SRCDIR)/kStd
INCLUDES += -I $(SRCDIR)/kRTLib
INCLUDES += -I $(SRCDIR)/kSimCore
INCLUDES += -I $(SRCDIR)/kEXE
INCLUDES += -I $(SRCDIR)/NetIFC
INCLUDES += -I $(SRCDIR)/kEOM
INCLUDES += -I $(SRCDIR)/kFCS
INCLUDES += -I $(SRCDIR)/kPwrP

#--- List of dependencies
KSTD_LIB:= $(LIBDIR)/kstd.a
KMATH_LIB:= $(LIBDIR)/kmath.a
KRT_LIB:= $(LIBDIR)/krtlib.a
KSIMCORE_LIB:= $(LIBDIR)/ksimcore.a
KEXE_LIB:= $(LIBDIR)/kexe.a
KEOM_LIB:= $(LIBDIR)/keom.a
KNETIFC_LIB:= $(LIBDIR)/netifc.a
KPWRP_LIB:= $(LIBDIR)/kpwrp.a
KFCS_LIB:= $(LIBDIR)/kfcs.a
MAINOBJ:= $(OBJDIR)/main.o

MAIN_DEPENDS = $(MAINOBJ) $(KSTD_LIB) $(KMATH_LIB) $(KRT_LIB) $(KSIMCORE_LIB) $(KEXE_LIB) 
MAIN_DEPENDS += $(KEOM_LIB) $(KPWRP_LIB) $(KFCS_LIB) $(KNETIFC_LIB)

LIBRARIES:= -lkeom -lksimcore -lkrtlib -lkmath -lkstd -lkexe -lrt -lnetifc -lkfcs -lkpwrp

#--- directives
vpath %.h ../include

ifeq ($(KDEBUG),1)
    VERBOS:= -Xlinker --verbose
else
    VERBOS:=
endif

all: $(OUTPUT)

#--- Clean tool ---
clean:
    -rm $(OBJDIR)/*.o
    -rm -R *.o
    -rm $(OBJDIR)/*.a
    -rm -R *.a
    -rm $(EXEDIR)/*
    -rm $(LIBDIR)/*.a
    @echo all object file deleted, executable deleted

#--------- Build the main app executable -------------

$(OUTPUT): $(MAIN_DEPENDS)
    @+echo
    @echo "===== Linking the App - Full Build ====="
    @$(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(VERBOS) -o $(OUTPUT) $(OBJDIR)/main.o -L$(LIBDIR) $(LIBRARIES)
    @echo "Application build successfull. "
    @+echo
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The traditional behavior of linkers is to search for external functions from left to right in the libraries specified on the command line. This means that a library containing the definition of a function should appear after any source files or object files which use it.

[Source](https://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/an_introduction_to_gcc/gccintro_18.html)